# Is there an easy way to add YTD giving to receipts?

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, configuration, receipts

We have a client that we moved from Donorperfect who brought up that they feel the receipt tools are incomplete without the ability to include YTD (year to date) giving on receipts. This seems like a simple and common request. Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 9):

Install Jamie McClelland's Summary Fields extension - see [here](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) - and insert Total Contributions this Year as a token.

Comment: I guess I was more looking for a transaction history of giving YTD. So if they have given a monthly donation it shows them a history of those individual donations. Similar to what you might receive as a tax receipt at the end of the year only this would be cumulative on every receipt.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for the Contributions Table Token extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/contributions-table-token

Comment: That is perfect! Awesome.